# Weekly Employee Report Generator PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, generator

## [Weekly Employee Report Generator PowerShell Script](https://github.com/Zoran-Jankov/Weekly-Employee-Report-Generator)

### Description

This script is used for generating a Markdown template file for weekly employee reports. In **`Settings.cfg`** file you can define the name and title of the employee, report title and report folder name, starting hour and working time, and the names of the days of the week, to cover all the languages. When you run the script it will first try to find existing file for current week and open it in the the default Markdown editor, and if it does not exist it will create one for current week, and then it will open newly created file.

#### Settings Example

```
EmployeeName = John Doe
EmployeeTitle = System Administrator
ReortFolderName = Weekly Reports
ReportTitle = Weekly report
StartingTime = 09:00
WorkingTime = 8
MondayName = Monday
TuesdayName = Tuesday
WednesdayName = Wednesday
ThursdayName = Thursday
FridayName = Friday
SaturdayName = Saturday
SundayName = Sunday
```

### PowerShell Script

```
$Date = Get-Date
$DayDecrement = 0
$Settings = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Settings.cfg" | ConvertFrom-StringData

switch ($Date.DayOfWeek) {
    'Monday' {
        $DayDecrement = 0
    }
    'Tuesday' {
        $DayDecrement = -1
    }
    'Wednesday' {
        $DayDecrement = -2
    }
    'Thursday' {
        $DayDecrement = -3
    }
    'Friday' {
        $DayDecrement = -4
    }
    'Saturday' {
        $DayDecrement = -5
    }
    'Sunday' {
        $DayDecrement = -6
    }
}
$MondayDate = $Date.AddDays($DayDecrement).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.")
$SundayDate = $Date.AddDays($DayDecrement + 6).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.")
$Settings = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Settings.cfg" | ConvertFrom-StringData

$ReportTitle = $Settings.ReportTitle + " $MondayDate - $SundayDate"
$Documents = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")
$ReportFolderName = $Settings.ReortFolderName
$ReportFullName = "$Documents\$ReportFolderName\$ReportTitle" + "md"

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ReportFullName)) {
    $DaysOfWeek = @(
        $Settings.MondayName
        $Settings.TuesdayName
        $Settings.WednesdayName
        $Settings.ThursdayName
        $Settings.FridayName
        $Settings.SaturdayName
        $Settings.SundayName
    )

    $Employee = "> " + $Settings.EmployeeName + " - " + $Settings.EmployeeTitle
    
    $ReportBody = "# $ReportTitle`n`n$Employee`n`n------`n`n"
    foreach ($Day in $DaysOfWeek) {
        $ReportBody += "## $Day " + $Date.AddDays($DayDecrement).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.")
        $DayDecrement ++
        $ReportBody += "`n`n------`n`n"
        for ($Hour = 0; $Hour -lt $Settings.WorkingTime; $Hour ++) {
            $Start = ([datetime]::ParseExact($Settings.StartingTime, "HH:mm", $null)).AddHours($Hour).ToString("HH:mm")
            $End = ([datetime]::ParseExact($Settings.StartingTime, "HH:mm", $null)).AddHours($Hour + 1).ToString("HH:mm")
            $ReportBody += "### $Start - $End`n`n- `n`n"
        }
        $ReportBody += "------`n`n"
    }
    
    New-Item -Path $ReportFullName -Force
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFullName -Value $ReportBody
}

Start-Process $ReportFullName
```

### [Generated Report Example](https://github.com/Zoran-Jankov/Weekly-Employee-Report-Generator/blob/main/Generated%20Report%20Example.md)

### Question

I am planning on creating a GUI for editing **`Settings.cfg`** file, and to have the option to select work days so not the whole week is created, just the days you work on. I would like your opinions on my little project and how to improve it.

Comment: [1] dotnet has a dayname enum >>> `[System.DayOfWeek]::GetNames([System.DayOfWeek])` <<< plus, it is culture aware. [2] you may want to consider using `Export/Import-CliXml` for your config files since that stores things in a way that neatly restores objects.